# Limit API response to 100 and iterate it over till the end of the Response

Tags: java, list, spring-boot, arraylist, webclient

I am having an API that will give more then 100 id as responses, but I need to pass this response as an body to anther API where it will take only 100 id as request body, I need to split these responses and send it in batches to another API, can anyone please help me to split these response to 100 and send it over to another.

Service class-

```
Workspaces workspace = new Workspaces(mw);
Flux<Workspaces> modifiedWorkspace = webClient.post().uri(URIDetails.MODIFIEDWORKSPACE)
.header("Authorization", bearerToken).body(Mono.just(mw), Workspaces.class).retrieve()
.bodyToFlux(Workspaces.class);
modifiedWorkspace.doOnNext(System.out::println).blockLast();
return null;
```

Workspaces model-

```
public class Workspaces {
private List<String> workspaces;
}
```

Main call-

```
Flux<ScanIDModel> modifiedWorkspaces;
final List<String> mw = new ArrayList<>();
for (Workspace w : modifiedWorkspaces) {
mw.add(w.getId());
}
modifiedWorkspaces = scanRespone(mw);
```

JSON BODY :

```
{
"workspaces": [
"6eret123",
"b129078v",
"ngy66553",
"erfc1153"
]
}
```

How can I Iterate it over and split the response in here. Please help me over to resolve this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think that for your use case the best option is to use the window operation.
https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#window-java.time.Duration-
This operator will open a new flux every n items, in your case every 100 items and then you can send this new flux to the other API.
AN example of this code would be:

```
  modifiedWorkspace
        .window(100)
        .doOnNext(flux -> Webclient.post().uri(anotheruri).body(flux))
        .subscribe();
```

Comment: I want to have it as List than Flux ,is the mentioned above one will be same?

Comment: yes, you only have to change the doOnNext operation to something like:

.doOnNext(flux -> flux.collectList().subscribe(l -> Webclient.post().uri(anotheruri).body(flux))

Answer (score 0):

Flux has a method [`buffer(int maxSize)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#buffer-int-) which will collect elements from the flux until max size and return a `Flux<List>` which you can then use in the next API. E.g.

```
Flux.just(1,2,3,4,5,6)
    .buffer(2)
    .flatMap(list -> /* List of 2 elements each*/ webClient.post().uri(uri).body(list).retrieve())
    .subscribe()
```

Another option is [`bufferTimeout(int maxSize, Duration maxTime)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#bufferTimeout-int-java.time.Duration-) that will not stall your pipeline if elements take longer to saturate.

Comment: If I dont want flux and use List can i use the same as mentioned above?

Comment: For pure java lists, you can use Guava library: `Lists.partition(workspaces, 100)`,
Or if you don't want to use another library, you can do:
`Flux.fromIterable(workspaces) ....` essentially, wrapping your list in a flux and doing the above.

Comment: List<List<Workspace>> batches = Lists.partition(modifiedWorkspacesWithDate, 100);

final List<String> modifiedWorkspace = new ArrayList<>();


for (Workspace workspace : batches) {
modifiedWorkspace.add(workspace.getId());}

I am trying to do like this but getting like this


-->  Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type List<Workspace> to Workspace

Comment: what mistake I am doing here?

Comment: Can you share the code from beginning to end? It's getting hard to grasp with pieces of code